# TaskDelay in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

```
string word = "sos";
    Dictionary<string, string> Codes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"a", ".-   "}, {"b", "-... "}, {"c", "-.-. "}, {"d", "-..  "}, 
            {"e", ".    "}, {"f", "..-. "}, {"g", "--.  "}, {"h", ".... "},
            {"i", "..   "}, {"j", ".--- "}, {"k", "-.-  "}, {"l", ".-.. "},
            {"m", "--   "}, {"n", "-.   "}, {"o", "---  "}, {"p", ".--. "}, 
            {"q", "--.- "}, {"r", ".-.  "}, {"s", "...  "}, {"t", "-    "}, 
            {"u", "..-  "}, {"v", "...- "}, {"w", ".--  "}, {"x", "-..- "}, 
            {"y", "-.-- "}, {"z", "--.. "}, {"0", "-----"}, {"1", ".----"}, 
            {"2", "..---"}, {"3", "...--"}, {"4", "....-"}, {"5", "....."}, 
            {"6", ".----"}, {"7", "..---"}, {"8", "...--"}, {"9", "....-"}    
        };



    async public void RunMorseCode()
    {


        foreach (char c in word.ToCharArray())
        {
            string rslt = Codes[c.ToString()].Trim();
            foreach (char c2 in rslt.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (c2 == '.')
                {

                    gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
                     await Task.Delay(100);


                }
                else if(c2 == '-')
                {

                    gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
                     await Task.Delay(1000);

                }
                gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1;

            }

        }
    }
```

Is turns black and stop working after that, Windows Store App, any idea?

Comment: After what? Is there an exception?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is logical. Solution:

```
gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1;
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

You could also use the Blend and create States with animations and storyboards etc

- [Animation overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295346.aspx)
- [Animate objects in XAML Designer (Videos)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171046.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this in Visual Studio 2015RC in a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. It worked in both cases but you better put another Task.Delay to your code, otherwise the blinking effect won't be visible - maybe this is what you considered as "turning black"?
I suggest you add another line at the end after

*gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1;*

e.g. add here

*await Task.Delay(100);*

This makes the blinking more visible and the app feels more "responsive".

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your `Task.Delay()` calls with this:

```
new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(milliseconds);
```

Apparently, `Task.Delay()` is [not really the most awesome thing for what you're trying to do](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/winappswithcsharp/thread/295e8ff1-812f-44de-8a72-ae3480d1060f).

Comment: `Task.Delay` would work fine here. The problem in the referenced MSDN thread is actually due to timer resolution. It's a well-known problem when delaying tiny amounts of time (e.g., 1 ms), but 100ms or 1000ms should not be seriously impacted.

Comment: Thanks - I just saw the thread and thought it might be useful.